# Customise Magento topLinks

Tags: magento

I need to customise Magento topLinks to include customer name on the Log Out link.

I understand that the label can be found in customer.xml but don't know how to include the customer name in to make it display like "Log Out (Customer Name)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This should help](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2011/06/how-to-change-my-account-menu-link-in.html). It explains how to add the customer name on "My account" item, but it should work the same for log out button also. It involves creating a simple extension and replacing the menu item you want with one that holds the customer name